# Yii - displaying external image with $data->value in GridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii

This has had me stomped for the last several hours, and I cannot find how to properly make it work. All the solutions are for local images, but mine crashes on the `:` in the `http://`.

This is what I have:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        'name',
        array(
            'name' => 'url',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value'=> 'CHtml::image(http://my.domain.com/images/' . $data->url . ')',
        ),
    ),
));
```

I have tried adding parameters like a class, escaping the domain, adding double quotes for the domain, but nothing has worked. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
'value'=>function($data) { return addslashes(CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/' . $data->url)); },
```

Works for me even without escaping the `//` using addslashes though.

For an external domain -

```
'value'=>function($data) { return addslashes(CHtml::image('http://www.google.com'.'/images/' . $data->url)); },
```

Comment: I want to use an external domain, not a relative path on my own domain.

Answer (score 1):

In value, you have to pass url as string in CHtml::image function.

Try below code:

```
 'value'=> 'CHtml::image("http://my.domain.com/images/' . $data->url . '")',
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        array(
            'name' => 'url',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($data) { return CHtml::image("http://my.domain.com/images/data->url"); },
        ),
```

I fixed it by using the above code. Both answers did not work as expected, sadly.